# object values not changing Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, object

Hi I am trying change values to the objects in my array
such as State from 'idle' to 'ready' . But when i run my code
it originally prints the new value but then when i try to print the array again
its back to the original values ?
here is some of the code thank you :)

```
public class PumpSystem {


private Pumps station[];
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
Attendant attendant = new Attendant();



public PumpSystem() {
    station = new Pumps[10];


    station[0] = new Pumps("P101", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[1] = new Pumps("P102", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[2] = new Pumps("P103", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[3] = new Pumps("P104", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[4] = new Pumps("P105", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[5] = new Pumps("P201", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[6] = new Pumps("P202", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[7] = new Pumps("P203", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[8] = new Pumps("P204", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    station[9] = new Pumps("P205", "Idle", "Default", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);


}


//************** Print-Stations ***********************
public void printStations() {
    for (int i = 0; i < station.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(" ID: " + station[i].getPumpID() + " --> " + " State: " + station[i].getState());
    }
}

//*********************** Switch statement for Statues change ************************************


public void updateModeSelect() {
    boolean endLoop = false;


    while (!endLoop) {
        menu();
        int option = stdin.nextInt();
        String wait = stdin.nextLine();
        switch (option) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println(" **** Enter new State **** \n");
                station[0].setState(stdin.nextLine() + "\n");
                System.out.println("Station: P101 State changed to: " + station[0].getState());
                attendant.attendantControls();
            case 1:
```

and i get this output :

```
     **** Enter new State **** 

Ready  <-- user input

Station: P101 State changed to: Ready

  
*** Logged in as Attendant  ***  
  (1) *** Stations ***
  (2) *** Change Pump State ***  
  (3) *** back to Main Menu *** 
  (4) *** Shut Down ***
```

so it works but then i print my array and its back to Idle?
this is my Pump class

```
public class Pumps {

    private String pumpID;
    private String state;
    private String fuelType;
    private double total;
    private double pumpOutPut;
    private double pumpInTake;



    //Constructors
    public Pumps ( String pumpID, String state, String fuelType, double total ,
                 double pumpOutPut, double pumpInTake){
        this.pumpID = pumpID;
        this.state =  state;
        this.fuelType = fuelType;
        this.total = total;
        this.pumpOutPut = pumpOutPut;
         this.pumpInTake = pumpInTake;

    }

    public String getPumpID() {
        return pumpID;
    }

    public void setPumpID(String newPumpID) {
        pumpID = newPumpID;
    }

    //*************MODE*********************

    public void setState(String newState) {
         state = newState;

    }



    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    //*************FUEL-TYPE*********************

    public void setFuelType(String newFuelType) {
        fuelType = newFuelType;
    }

    public String getFuelType() {
        return fuelType;
    }
    //*************PUMP-IN-TAKE*********************


    public void setPumpInTake(double newPumpInTake) {
        pumpInTake = newPumpInTake;
    }


    //**************PUMP-OUT-PUT********************
    public void setPumpOutPut(double newPumpOutPut) {
        pumpOutPut = newPumpOutPut;
    }

    //*************TOTAL*********************

    public void setTotal(double newTotal) {
        total = newTotal;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return pumpID +state + fuelType + total + pumpInTake + pumpOutPut;
    }
        //**********************************
}
```

this is what the attendant does with the attendantControls()

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Attendant {


    public void attendantControls(){

        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        Main main = new Main();
        boolean endLoop = false;
        Manager manager = new Manager();
        PumpSystem pumpSystem =  new PumpSystem();

        while (!endLoop) {
            menu();
            int selection = stdin.nextInt();
            switch (selection) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("*** Stations *** ");
                    pumpSystem.printStations();
                    System.out.println("*************************************************");



                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("*** Pump State Managment ***");
                    pumpSystem.updateModeSelect();
                    System.out.println("*************************************************");
                    System.out.println("*************************************************");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("*** Main Menu ***");
                    endLoop = true;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input - Please Select Options  1-3");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    private  void menu() {
        System.out.println("  \n*** Logged in as Attendant  ***  ");
        System.out.println("  (1) *** Stations ***");
        System.out.println("  (2) *** Change Pump State ***  ");
        System.out.println("  (3) *** back to Main Menu *** ");
        System.out.println("  (4) *** Shut Down *** ");

    }
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see the implementation of Pumps.

Comment: can you post the code where you changing the state

Comment: btw make sure to put breaks after cases

Comment: how do you print the array?

Comment: and what does `attendant.attendantControls();` do?

Comment: Feels like you are missing `break;` statements, your case:1 get's run after case:0

Comment: I updated my question with the Pumps class , ( i think anyway im new to how stackOverflow works sorry)

Comment: @JovoH with the PrintStations method :)

Comment: @mangusta thank you :)

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku I have updated my question with the Pump class :)

Comment: Hi there, I think you problem is because you are changing only the very first element in your array here `station >>>>>[0] <<<<< .setState(stdin.nextLine() + "\n");` So verify whether when you print the first one changes. You need to have a way to seek which one  you want to change, grab it from the array and then change it :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos hi I thought that is how I do change the element is that not how Its done :( ?

Comment: @MilaRose so which number do you select in the loop inside "attendantControls" method? according to the loop, it has to output something, regardless of which number was selected but you show only the output of "menu" method. There should be something else

Comment: @mangusta how so you mean? the menu method is to print the menu , well its supposed to i guess i'm doing something wrong?  and then i select  which takes me to the pumpSystem.updatemodeselect ( which is supposed to be updateState)

Comment: @mangusta it is printed, the question is why the array doesn't update but it does update once printed with the  ` System.out.println("Station: P101 State changed to: " + station[0].getState());` yet when I go back to the  printStations loop it goes back to the hard coded part